# How do I do a reset of the Bootstrap modal window without reloading the page ? Using PHP , jQuery, AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a comment system. The user can report a bad comment (jquery and AJAX). When there are several comments for the same post the Bootstrap modal window retains the message from the previous report. 
How do I do a reset of the modal window without reloading the page?

post.php

```
<button type="button" id="showModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm reporting" data-comment-id = "<?= $comment->getId() ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reportModal"></button>

<div class="modal fade" id="reportModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="title-report" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="title-report">Confirm reporting</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit-reporting">Validate</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="commentId"  value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

report.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.reporting').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#commentId').val($(this).data('comment-id'));
  });
  $('.submit-reporting').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var commentId = $('#commentId').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'post/moderateComment/' + commentId,
      success: function(){
                  $(".modal-body").html("<p>The report has been forwarded!</p>");
                  $('.submit-reporting').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                  $('[data-comment-id = "'+commentId+'"]').hide();
                }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by reset the modal?

Comment: Are you talking about the content of `.modal_body`? Bootstrap provides an event that fires before the modal gets shown, so just add a handler function for that event, and set this element empty in there.

Comment: "the message from the previous report"  What is the difference in messaging?  From a glance at your code, I'm not seeing any variable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to have a modal with it's initial state? If that is so, you can do it by tweaking your modal when it is opened and resetting the elements that you want. So in your javascript, you should have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.reporting').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Clean your message here*** with something like 
    //$('.elementWHereMessageIs').empty(); //Is faster than text('') or html('')
    $(".modal-body").empty(); // I don't know if this is the message you want to empty?

    $('#commentId').val($(this).data('comment-id'));
  });
  $('.submit-reporting').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var commentId = $('#commentId').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'post/moderateComment/' + commentId,
      success: function(){
                  $(".modal-body").html("<p>The report has been forwarded!</p>");
                  $('.submit-reporting').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                  $('[data-comment-id = "'+commentId+'"]').hide();
                }
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!
Leo.

Comment: I'm confused it works with your solution, Leo. Sorry for my lack of knowledge many thanks to you and other people for taking the time to answer me.

Comment: Well is nothing to be confused about, each time you are opening the modal, you are cleaning the message that is contained in the modal. If it works can you mark the answer as resolved? Thanks

Comment: Of course, but where? I'm a beginner you'll probably notice

Comment: @yanga yes it's good for me and the community as well! So on the left side of the beggining text of my answer, next to "I think what you are looking.." you will see a 0 number and two grey triangle arrows facing up and down, just press the one on top.